# Creating subdomains dynamically for an application

Tags: php, dynamic, subdomain

I want to create subdomains dynamically through a PHP script or something similar. I've seen lots of sites that create subdomains for individual users, or for new forum spaces. I'm just wondering how that works, and how I can implement it in my system.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look into [wildcard subdomains](http://steinsoft.net/index.php?site=programming/articles/apachewildcarddomain). Once you have all of the "subdomains" going to the right place, you can use url rewriting and/or some other mixture of redirecting to create the effect of subdomains without having to constantly update a httpd.conf setup and/or DNS tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache on a Linux box, you can create new VirtualHosts for each subdomain.  Here is a [guide for Debian/Ubuntu](http://www.debuntu.org/2006/02/22/7-virtual-hosting-using-apache-2) which may also work for other distros.

Basically: each entry goes into its own file under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled.  Whenever an entry is added/changed/removed, you run 'sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload' to update the virtual hosts / subdomains.