# How to create subdomains dynamically using php script?

Tags: php

Is it possible to create subdomains dynamically on server using php script?
I want to create it.

My server is on hostmonster. And I want to create subdomains dynamically.

Comment: No you can't. If so this is a big security bug.

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297681/creating-subdomains-dynamically-for-an-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're after, but here's something to think about.

Your DNS needs to be configured to support it by having a [wilcard dns record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) that points to your web server. For instance `*.mydomain.com`.

Once done, you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to determine which host is being accessed. Alternatively, you could let PHP add the subdomain inside the web server configuration.

I wouldn't recommend doing this unless you really really know what you're doing.

Comment: how to configure DNS by having wildcard DNS record. My basic requirement is that i am working on moodle-elearning system. I setup one main moodle instance . I develope moodle script like that multiple instances can work on single moodle script. Just database for each & every instance are different.  Now client want's that he can setup no. of clients (moodle instance) dynamically. My configuration script is ready . I can generate database dynamically. One thing is remaining is that subdomains setup  dynamically.  For example :   main.domain.com   , main2.domain.com , main3.domain.com....

Answer (score 0):

"using php script".

If I'm not wrong it sounds you want to create virtual sub-domains on your site in order to display e.g. for each user such as wordpress.com or tumblr.

I think it's possible with `.htaccess` even I have never tried it, but maybe gives an idea.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule /user.php?username=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```